# Trigonometry: Find points coordinates in equally arms triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, coordinate-systems

h have a equally arms triangle. The angle on point C is not 90 degrees.

[image]

I have:

1. The coordinates of point $C(C_x, C_y)$
2. The coordinates of the end point of $h$, $H(H_x, H_y)$
3. The length of $C$ (example: 20)

I need to find the coordinates of point $A(A_x, A_y)$ and $B(B_x, B_y)$.

My project is drawing a line from a node to a point in space (in red):
[image]

I know the position of the node $C(C_x, C_y)$ ("No name" red circle) and the point the line is drawn to $H(H_x, H_y)$

I need to coordinates of 2 equally distant points (in green) around the H point. I want to set the length of distance from the H point to the green points.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the end point of $h$?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.
This site uses
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: Thank you I will keep that in mind when i post new questions. But in this case I have no idea how to do it and have no progress, so nothing is going to be a thing i already know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $H = (H_x, H_y)$ is the point in the middle of $A$ and $B$, then $H_y = A_y = B_y$.

Further $A_x = C_x - c/2$, $B_x = C_x + c/2$.

Comment: Not exactly in my case. The triangle will not lay on the coordinate system and it's not that simple. I think ... And what is 'c' ?